# Colocar texto embaixo de slider de imagem sem quebrar prejudicar o layout

Tags: html, css

Possuo um slider de imagens assim: 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

preciso colocar "legendas" embaixo de cada uma das imagens. 
Como está no html:

```
<div id="pic-0">
    <a href="/ModuloPublico/AssociacaoCooperativa/Index/101">
        <img src="url da imagem" alt="Licor de Maracujá com Mousse" width="302" height="192" widht="100%">
    </a>
    <a href="/ModuloPublico/AssociacaoCooperativa/Index/101">
        <img src="url da imagem" alt="Licor de maracuja concentrado" width="302" height="192" widht="100%">
    </a>

    <a class="previous" href="#pic-3" onclick="bgenScroll();">&lt;</a>
    <a class="next" href="#pic-1" onclick="bgenScroll();">&gt;</a>

</div>
```

Ao tentar colocar legenda embaixo de cada imagem, o slider se "quebra" ficando da seguinte forma:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como ficou o html:

```
<div id="pic-0">
    <a href="/ModuloPublico/AssociacaoCooperativa/Index/101">
        <img src="url da imagem" alt="Licor de Maracujá com Mousse" width="302" height="192" widht="100%">
    </a>"Licor de Maracujá com Mousse"
    <a href="/ModuloPublico/AssociacaoCooperativa/Index/101">
        <img src="url da imagem" alt="Licor de maracuja concentrado" width="302" height="192" widht="100%">
    </a>"Licor de maracuja concentrado"

    <a class="previous" href="#pic-3" onclick="bgenScroll();">&lt;</a>
    <a class="next" href="#pic-1" onclick="bgenScroll();">&gt;</a>

</div>
```

Classe CSS:

```
.fieldset {
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
        padding: 25px;
    }

    .legend {
        width: inherit; /* Or auto */
        padding: 0 10px; /* To give a bit of padding on the left and right */
        border-bottom: none;
    }

    .gallerywrapper {
        margin-top: 5000px;
        width: 100%;
        height: 270px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        position: relative;
        font-family: verdana, arial, sans-serif;
    }

        .gallerywrapper .gallery {
            position: absolute;
            text-decoration: none;
            margin-top: 50%;
            left: 0;
            top: 0;
            height: 270px;
            width: 100%;
            overflow: hidden;
            text-align: center;
        }

            .gallerywrapper .gallery div {
                width: 100%;
                height: 900px;
                padding-top: 10px;
                position: relative;
            }

                .gallerywrapper .gallery div img {
                    clear: both;
                    display: inline-block;
                    margin: 0 auto;
                    border: 0;
                }

                .gallerywrapper .gallery div h3 {
                    padding: 10px 0 0 0;
                    margin: 0;
                    font-size: 18px;
                }

                .gallerywrapper .gallery div p {
                    padding: 5px 0;
                    margin: 0;
                    font-size: 12px;
                    line-height: 18px;
                }


    .gallery .previous {
        display: inline;
        float: left;
        margin-left: 10px;
        margin-top: 80px;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    .gallery .next {
        display: inline;
        float: right;
        margin-right: 10px;
        margin-top: 80px;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
```

Alguma forma de deixar a legenda de cada imagem, embaixo de cada imagem?

Comment: Já testou colocando o texto junto com a imagem dentro da tag <a></a> ? Com o código que vc postou ai não da para simular o erro apresentado na imagem, ai fica difícil te ajudar...

Comment: @hugocsl sim, fica da mesma forma, porem o texto fica com link

Comment: O texto não pode ter link ou tanto faz?

Comment: @hugocsl tanto faz, só é preciso que cada legenda fique embaixo de cada foto sem prejudicar o layout

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aqui tem uma opção simples que pode te ajudar. O conceito é escrever a "legenda" no atributo global `title` do `link`, e depois usando um *pseudo-elemento* `::after` vc vai mostrar na tela o que estiver escrito dentro desse `title`. Parece complicado mas não é rss

Sua tag `<a>` tem que ter um atributo `title=""` e o `class="slide"`

```
<a class="slide" href="#" title="Licor de Maracujá com Mousse">
```

Agora com esse CSS `a.slide::after {content: attr(title);}` eu vou pegar o que está escrito no `title` do `<a>` e colocar abaixo da imagem.

```
#pic-0 a.slide::after {
  content: attr(title);
  ...
}
```

Veja o resultado final com o seu código como ficaria.

```css
#pic-0 a.slide {
position: relative;
text-align: center;
}
#pic-0 a.slide::after {
content: attr(title);
position: absolute;
display: inline-block;
bottom: -20px;
left: 0;
}

.fieldset {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 25px;
}

.legend {
  width: inherit;
  /* Or auto */
  padding: 0 10px;
  /* To give a bit of padding on the left and right */
  border-bottom: none;
}

.gallerywrapper {
  margin-top: 5000px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 270px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  font-family: verdana, arial, sans-serif;
}

.gallerywrapper .gallery {
  position: absolute;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 270px;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
}

.gallerywrapper .gallery div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 900px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  position: relative;
}

.gallerywrapper .gallery div img {
  clear: both;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 0;
}

.gallerywrapper .gallery div h3 {
  padding: 10px 0 0 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.gallerywrapper .gallery div p {
  padding: 5px 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 18px;
}


.gallery .previous {
  display: inline;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-top: 80px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.gallery .next {
  display: inline;
  float: right;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-top: 80px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="pic-0">
  <a class="slide" href="/ModuloPublico/AssociacaoCooperativa/Index/101" title="Licor de Maracujá com Mousse">
    <img src="https://placecage.com/100/100" alt="Licor de Maracujá com Mousse" width="302" height="192" widht="100%">
  </a>
  <a class="slide" href="/ModuloPublico/AssociacaoCooperativa/Index/101" title="Licor de Maracujá com Mousse">
    <img src="https://placecage.com/100/100" alt="Licor de maracuja concentrado" width="302" height="192" widht="100%">
  </a>

  <a class="previous" href="#pic-3" onclick="bgenScroll();">&lt;</a>
  <a class="next" href="#pic-1" onclick="bgenScroll();">&gt;</a>

</div>
```

Comment: quase deu, porem a outra imagem desceu em vez de ficar do lado da primeira conforme print: https://imgur.com/a/NT47N8Z

Comment: @StandAlone editei a resposta, mudei o CSS para ajustar conforme precisa, da uma olhada agora, copia as duas primeira classes que coloquei lá `#pic-0 a.slide ` e `#pic-0 a.slide ::after` que tb coloquei algumas propriedades a mais, ficou assim http://prntscr.com/nuezv9

Comment: boaa valeu vc é o cara kkkkkkkk a lengenda tava em cima da foto só alterei o bottom: -120px; e deu certo muito obrigado.

Comment: @StandAlone legal que deu certo ai! abs 